# Find E and B from vector potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics

I have a vector potential given by:

$\mathbf{A}(x,t) = \mathbf{e}_{y}\frac{1}{2} e^{-(x-ct)^{2}/{4a^{2}}}$

Now, the question is "Determine the **E** and **B** under the condition that the scalar potential vanishes $V = 0$."

But I'm not quite sure what it means when $V=0$ ?

As far as I can see, the **B**-field is given by:

$\mathbf{B}=\nabla \times \mathbf{A}$

And then I have that:

$\mathbf{E} = -\nabla V$

So is it just this straightforward ?
That I find the **B**-field from **A**, and since $V = 0$, the **E**-field is zero, or am I doing it wrong ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relation $\mathbf{E} = -\nabla V$ holds only in the absence of vector potential, otherwise the electric field changes to
$$
\mathbf{E} = -\nabla V-\frac{\partial\mathbf{A}}{\partial t}.
$$
The reason for this is that when you introduce vector potential by $\mathbf{B} = \nabla\times\mathbf{A}$, Faraday's law reads
$$
\nabla\times\mathbf{A}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}) =
\nabla\times\left(\mathbf{E}+\frac{\partial\mathbf{A}}{\partial t}\right) = 0.
$$
This can be solved generally by putting the bracket equal to a gradient of a scalar function $-\nabla V$ which gives the result for electric field in terms of both scalar and vector potentials given above.

Comment: So actually, since $V=0$ the $\mathbf{E}$-field is just the negative derivative of $\mathbf{A}$ with respect to $t$ ?

Comment: @DenverDang Exactly :)

Answer (score 2):

The expression for the electric field includes derivatives of the vector potential with respect to time.